# short path of current directory in cmd windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I wish there's a way to show a shortened directory path in windows CMD, I searched the internet and found this command:

```
for %I in (.) do %~nxI
```

if you enter this command in cmd and press enter it would show the current dir name. suppose I was standing in my desktop it will print:

```
Desktop
```

thats enough for me. but not yet, I tried to save this command in a environment system variable then pass that variable to cmd line, but this way it would print the command itself instead of the result.
created a variable named PROMPT then value is:

```
%username%$s$p$s$d$t$_-$g$s
```

result is:

```
my_username full_path_to_current_dir date time newline dash greater_than_mark(>)

Mahdi c:\Users\Mahdi\Desktop 23/02/2020 19:27:38.93
```

->this is an screenshot of what Ihave: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auicf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature avaible in the standard prompt.
You potentially could hack it using echo off and [doskeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey),
but I would instead suggest checking out one of the many alternatives such as [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) or [Zoc](https://www.emtec.com/zoc/)

Comment: thanks, cmd is very fast in Windows, even powershell is a little bit slow. but I have no idea about alternatives or maybe a bit underestimating them.

Comment: No, there is something to be said about that for sure.
You wont find one faster than the orginal. 
You can use Echo off to turn off the orginal, than implement a custom one by doskeying a letter,
like e=<your string> $* that may work but it would be troublesome.

Comment: Have you looked at the new terminal project?
You might find some answers [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=|" %I In (""%UserName%"|"%CD%"") Do @Prompt %~I$s%~nxJ$s$d$t$_-$g$s
```

---

Alternatively, if you wanted it setting to a variable, run the prompt command inside another for loop, and capture the output of that with the `Set` command.

Comment: hi, that works as the same I explained in my description, I have to enter this command with an enter to work. but I want to save it in a environment variable then use it without pressing Enter

Comment: I couldn't understand your instruction about how to save it in a environment variable

Comment: Your question no longer matches your provided edit, and is no longer clear. I thought that you were simply wanting to replace `$P`, _(current drive and path)_, with the current directory name only. It appears now as if you're trying to capture three lines as a value to a variable. Can you please explain exactly what you're trying to do? Saving a variable which contains the date, and more especially the time, means that as soon as you've defined it, it is already inaccurate, _(those values aren't dynamic)_. Can you also explain how you're intending to use that variable, later in the session?

Comment: hi, thanks for attention. yes I want to replace $P with a shortened path, but there's no way. the command that you provide has a restriction which anytime we want to use it has to entered manually. but I want to find a way to enter it just once and work for ever

Comment: As I said, if you save it as an "environment system variable", the date and time will be set to those which were in effect at the time you defined it. Variables are simply strings, not commands. You need to properly explain what the purpose of this is, what exactly are you trying to achieve? `%PROMPT%` is already a special variable, _(you can see it by entering `Echo %Prompt%` or `Set Prompt` in your cmd.exe window)_. Are you just wanting to output the three line prompt string as a new prompt whenever you need it, and then have it return to the default `$P$G` afterwards? or something else?

Comment: I think you should test it yourself. look at the image Linked, create a env. variable called PROMPT, then set the value in image for it, except the %CDIR%. it's not harmful anyway, save it by pressing Ok,then again Ok. then open your cmd and look what has changed? that's cool, except the full path of directory (for me at least)

Comment: I think you should answer my questions. As I've already indicated, my answer was to use the current directory name instead of the full path to the current directory, _(`$P`)_. I cannot help you with implementing changes to it, until you provide context and an actual replicable issue.